# VBA set spreadsheet font size and row size?

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a convenient way of setting the worksheet's font size and row height from VBA?

Comment: Try recording a macro ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This ought to work:

```
Sub SetFormat()
    With ActiveSheet
        .Cells.Font.Size = "12" 
        .Cells.RowHeight = 25.5
    End With
End Sub
```